# Dynamic rowspan table in PHP

Tags: php, html-table

I have a problem getting a table to work.
I want to adjust a printable form for order list (opencart),
but I want address box on left and products ordered on right.
The problem is the number of products varies per order, so using rowspan on the address box does not work (I left the rowspan in the code).

```
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td><b><?php echo $text_to; ?></b></td>
           <td><b><?php echo $column_product; ?></b></td>
          <td class="text-center"><b><?php echo $column_quantity; ?></b></td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody><tr>
          <td rowspan="10"><?php echo $order['shipping_address']; ?><br/><br/>
            <?php echo $order['telephone']; ?>
            <br />
            <?php if ($order['shipping_method']) { ?>
            <b><?php echo $text_shipping_method; ?></b> <?php echo $order['shipping_method']; ?><br />
            <?php } ?></td></tr>
        <?php foreach ($order['product'] as $product) { ?>
          <td><?php echo $product['name']; ?>
            <?php foreach ($product['option'] as $option) { ?>
            <br />
            &nbsp;<small> - <?php echo $option['name']; ?>: <?php echo $option['value']; ?></small>
            <?php } ?></td>
          <td class="text-center"><?php echo $product['quantity']; ?></td>
</tr>
        <?php } ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have all the information available it seems so you just need to change:

```
<td rowspan="10">
```

to:

```
<td rowspan="<?php echo count($order['product']); ?>">
```

However, you do need to check the generated html as it looks like you are not generating valid rows so you might need to change the logic a bit.

Comment: thanks that line is definately what i needed, i am now one step closer, but i am still getting one product display underneath instead of to the right, if i have 4 products 3 are lined up nicely on the right and one is underneath, if only one product it is underneath

Comment: job done i just had a </tr> i forgot to remove when playing about, thanks a lot for your help.